# Servicefabric nodes not coming online

Tags: azure, docker, containers

I am debugging a cluster there nodes are not coming online after deployment using a ARM template. I think the issue is something to do with the certificate.

I have the following events that might help figuring out what the issue is:

```
SecurityUtil::GetX509SvrCredThumbprint(LocalMachine, My, FindByThumbprint:6a187334b4ba95589cd5ee733b9ca1c3499eab5f) failed: FABRIC_E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
Unable to acquire ssl credentials: FABRIC_E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
failed to set security settings to { provider=SSL protection=EncryptAndSign certType = 'cluster' store='LocalMachine/My' findValue='FindByThumbprint:6a187334b4ba95589cd5ee733b9ca1c3499eab5f' remoteCertThumbprints='6a187334b4ba95589cd5ee733b9ca1c3499eab5f' certChainFlags=40000000 isClientRoleInEffect=false claimBasedClientAuthEnabled=false }: FABRIC_E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
Failed to set security on transport: FABRIC_E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
federation open failed with FABRIC_E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
Fabric Node open failed with error code = FABRIC_E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
HostedService: _nt1vm_0 on node id 72e0ec579b75d9847ba5a43d6b365d7c terminated unexpectedly with code 7167 and process name Fabric.exe
```

The thumbprint matches the expected cert used in the template deployment.

The certificate was created in c# and stored in a secret with `var certBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(x509Certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));` and contenttype = `application/x-pkcs12`

Comment: Noticed that there was a typo in the code, -1 vs 1 - so the certs i generated is expired instead of 1 year valid :( checking now that this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using expired certificates which caused this. :(

Comment: How did you fix this? I have a test environment that got abandoned and the certs expired, so same situation